# ReactJS this.state.feed.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I try to display the result RSS feed with the map function. Before displaying I use rss-parser npm package to parse the result of the request. As you can see on the following code I stock the result in a state. I have no compiling error you can see on the following images.

```js
import React from "react";
import {
    Card,
    CardHeader,
    CardBody
} from "shards-react";
import * as Parser from 'rss-parser';

var parser = new Parser();
const CORS_PROXY = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";

class DisplayRss extends React.Component{
    constructor (props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            feed : []
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        const feedd = await parser.parseURL(CORS_PROXY + 'https://fr.blog.ecosia.org/rss/');
        console.log("Yoda le boss !", feedd);
        this.setState({ feed : feedd});
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <Card small className="blog-comments">
                <CardHeader className="border-bottom">
                    <h6 className="m-0">RSS Viewer  </h6>
                </CardHeader>
                <CardBody className="p-0">
                    {this.state.feed.map((item, i) => (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                            <a href={item.link}>{item.link}</a>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </CardBody>
            </Card>
        );
    }
}

export default DisplayRss;
```

[image: Error this.state.feed.map is not a function.]

Comment: Please provide the result of  `console.log("Yoda le boss !", feedd);`. What is sure is that it's not an Array

Comment: @farvilain Yes with  ```console.log(typeof feedd)``` it's an Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should study the return value. It's an XML tree with this structure after parsing:

[image]

So the path is

```
this.state.feed.items
```